# Ruby - sort array of objects by attribute in descending order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, sorting

I have this Json array of objects

```
"students": [{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "age": "14",
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Victoria",
    "last_name": "Secret",
    "age": "9",
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Jim",
    "last_name": "Morrison",
    "age": "16",
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "first_name": "Jack",
    "last_name": "Daniels",
    "age": "7",
  },
  }]
```

I want to display them in my `index.html.erb` **sorted by age** in **DESC** order. I'm half way there, I have manage to sort them, however not in exact DESC order. This is my loop

```
<% @classroom['students'].sort_by { |st| st['age'] }.each do |student| %>
```

This is the result I want:

```
16,  Jim,     Morrison
14,  John,    Doe
9,  Victoria, Secret
7,  Jack,     Daniels
```

This is what I get instead:

```
14,  John,    Doe
16,  Jim,     Morrison
7,  Jack,     Daniels
9,  Victoria, Secret
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed to make the age a number

```
@classroom['students'].sort_by { |st| -st['age'].to_i }
```

I added a `-` because you want them in descending order. Otherwise

```
@classroom['students'].sort_by { |st| st['age'].to_i }.reverse
```

Comment: Correct, well spotted! One additional question if thats ok.. Is it considered best practice to have the `sort_by` block in my view and then append the `.each` to loop through the objects, or there's a more elegant way to do it? just for better readability

Comment: I'd leave the `sort_by` stuff in the action and in the view just `@students.each do`

Comment: Sorry just one more question. Each student has a birthdate attribute as this example `1997-09-26T10:40:00.000+01:00`, How can I convert the date to human readable format?  I tried `<td><%= student['dob'].strftime('%d-%m-%Y, %H:%M') %></td>`, but this breaks the code

Comment: `undefined method `strftime' for "2017-09-26T20:40:00.000+01:00":String`

Comment: @Ursus,
Hey! Good answer, but, as I know - using `#sort_by` with `#reverse` - should works faster ;)

Comment: Sure, that's valid too.

Comment: I get only the date (not time) as a mysql format, like 2017-09-26, although I have same format set as you

Comment: Oh, my fault. Try this one `<td><%= Date.parse(student['dob']).strftime('%d-%m-%Y, %H:%M') %></td>`

Comment: Worked with DateTime correct. `DateTime.parse(student['dob']).strftime('%d-%m-%Y, %H:%M')`