# C++ - How to order nested containers in first step and iterate through them in order in second step?

Tags: c++, iteration, std

given the variable of different nested containers.

```
std::pair<NonTerminal, std::vector<std::vector<Symbol>>> productions;
```

How can I order the pair-entries ascending from 0 to ..., such that I can maybe make use of an `::iterator` - if even possible/necessary (better way of organization?)

I thought of nesting the above in another pair like this:

```
std::pair<int, std::pair<NonTerminal, std::vector<std::vector<Symbol>>>> productions;
```

How could I then in ascending order iterate over my internal representation of grammatical productions (where the `NonTerminal` of the inner `std::pair` is the right-hand-side of the production, and the `std::vector` the right-hand-side.)

Thanks !

EDIT:

What I want is give a total order to the productions

```
std::pair<NonTerminal, std::vector<std::vector<Symbol>>> productions;
```

and iterate over them in ascending order.

@ jarod42: Here ([Ruby - sort array of objects by attribute in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433858/ruby-sort-array-of-objects-by-attribute-in-descending-order)) is a good example how to order by any attribute in ascending/descending order

Comment: I don't understand what you want... Possibly give examples.

Comment: We have no idea what do you mean by "*order to the productions*".

Comment: Order by *what*?

Comment: Given `productions = {NT_A, {{S_D, S_B}, {S_A, S_C}}};`, what do you expect?

Comment: Does this answer your quesiton? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects. Frankly, you again made the mistake of making it more complicated than necessary. There is a simple answer to "How to sort vectors of any type? (with a custom predicate)" and the answer is basically the same no matter what is the actual type of elements

Comment: the link I gave should help. What is unclear in your question is 1) what are the elements you want to sort? `Symbol`s? or `std::vector<Symbol>`s? 2) What determines if element `a` should come before element `b`? In other words you need to define `a < b`. Once you got that straight, you can apply answers from that link

Comment: idclev, you become my saviour :D but still, if i wanted to make the order an own explicit entity/attribute in c++, how would I proceed ? In Ruby it's an easy task.

Comment: Oh, the innermost vector just by the order in which I added the items.

Comment: Showing equivalent of what you want in ruby might help to understand what you want...

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but maybe what you want is a comparator. Its an object, a callable, that specifies the order that is used for sorting